# Setting a variable to the contents of a text file

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, txt

In JavaScript, I have been trying to make a function that sets the innerHTML of a paragraph element into a local .txt file's contents. So I want to extract the text from a file into a paragraph on the webpage.

I have done some research, but none of the techniques worked.

Comment: Is the file on the client or server?

Comment: If it's on the server, use `fetch()` to retrieve it, and then assign the response text to `.innerHTML`. If it's on the client, you have to use the File API to read it.

Comment: Please show what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: The file is local on my pc.

Comment: I tried Window.open(file), but I don't want it to open I want it as a variable.

Comment: Does [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications) help you?

Comment: No. I already have a text file on my system in the same directory as the HTML file. I want to set the innerHTML of the <p> tag to the contents of the text file.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. For security reasons, the browser may only access local files after they have been "uploaded" by the user. Just freely accessing a local file is prohibited, and with good reason.

Comment: Ok. Then I will have to upload files to the server to fetch them?

Comment: And is it still not possible if I run an .hta file?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found out you can easily make an iframe and link it to the text file's path via Iframe.src = path/to/text.txt;

Comment: @BadIdeaException That's not true. The File API requires the user to select the file from a chooser, like they do when uploading

Comment: @Barmar That's why I put upload in quotation marks. My point was, you can't just access the file system without user interaction. But you're right I could have phrased that more clearly.

Comment: And the simple answer is that browser security prohibits JS from accessing files without the user selecting it. Otherwise, any web site could upload your files without your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I have created a JavaScript example as per your requirement. try it:

```js
function readTextFile() {
        var fileAttach = document.getElementById('fileAttach');

        if (fileAttach.files.length > 0) {
            var file = fileAttach.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var fileTxt = e.target.result;
                var container = document.getElementById('fileTxt');
                var lines = fileTxt.split('\n');
                lines.forEach(function (line) {
                    if (line.trim() !== '') {
                        var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
                        paragraph.textContent = line;
                        container.appendChild(paragraph);
                    }
                });
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            alert('Please select a file.');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('fileAttach').addEventListener('change', readTextFile);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileAttach" />
<div id="fileTxt"></div>
```

Comment: Can I set the FileAttach variable to the file's path/URL?

Comment: This doesn't work as I want to link a file locally available on my system not manually upload one.

Comment: @Hawimhaks There's no upload here. The user just selects a local file from a chooser and it's displayed immediately. Browser security prohibits JavaScript from selecting the file by itself.